# Deploy iOS 5 app on an iPad 1

Tags: ios

I am currently developing an application for iOS and while it works fine on the simulator, I would like to run it on an actual device.
Unfortunately, I only have an iPad 1.

I’m using OS X Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 and I set the iOS Deployment Target for the project to iOS 5.1.
I understand that I won’t be able to run it on the iOS 5.1 Simulator with Mavericks, but I was wondering if I would still be able to run it on an iPad 1 ?

I can’t find that information anywhere and I just want to be sure it will work before paying the 99$ fee to deploy on the real hardware.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPad

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457458/running-an-ios-application-in-a-device-with-ios-5-1-1-using-xcode-5

Comment: @sbarow FYI these are two completely different questions and if you are trying to mark them as duplicates this one was asked first.

Comment: @Popeye I had the same thought at first, but I think sbarow is just posting it as a heads-up, since it's likely something the OP will run into.

Comment: @Popeye thanks for that but I didn't try and mark this as a duplicate I thought it would be of interest seeing as though the other guy was having issues running on iOS 5.1 (which proves you can do it) and might help the OP if he runs into any issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a first generation iPad up to iOS 5.1.1, which will work for testing iOS 5.1 apps.

If you intend to release your app to Apple's App Store, keep in mind that Apple has released a statement saying that all apps "must be optimized for iOS 7", so you may still need a newer device for testing. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a))