# Running an iOS application in a device with iOS 5.1.1, using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install an iOS application in my iPad running in iOS 5.1.1. When i launch it with Xcode with the development profile, i am getting the following errors :

> Xcode cannot install or launch applications supporting the 64-bit
>   architecture on devices running iOS versions prior to 6.0. This
>   configuration is supported for distribution through the iOS App Store,
>   but cannot be used during development with Xcode. To continue, edit
>   the Run scheme action and select a build configuration that does not
>   include the 64-bit architecture.

I have tried to change the building architecture by removing the arm64 but i have the same error.

I have tried to install it with testflight by building an ipa with an adhoc provision profile but the same error repeats.

How i can test my application in real device running iOS 5.1.1, building with Xcode 5

[image: Valid architectures]

Comment: I have xcode 5.1 and got the same situation that you described. I try delete arm64 from Valid Architectures with no success. Did you know if we can test in real device running iOS 5.1.1 building with Xcode 5.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a test target that has no arm64 within valid architectures.

See screenshot, check that you don't have arm64.

[image]

Comment: I have removed the arm64 from the Architectures and not in the valid Architectures. Removing it from the Valide architectures solved my problem. Will investigate more deeply. Thanks

Comment: How about adding a build configuration instead of a target? That seems more maintainable to me. Targets require you add and remove resources in tandem, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Build Active Architecture Only to Yes for the Debug scheme fixed this for me. This is shown in the screen shot of the accepted answer and it's possible that is the real solution, rather than what the accepted answer describes.